# Rest API from nodejs to https url with port 8443 throwing error

Tags: node.js, api, tomcat, npm

I'm trying to make an API call from nodejs to tomcat server using http/https module

I have two options for api url

1. http://samleapiurl.com/getdata - This works fine and i'm getting reponse

   ```
   var options = {
       host: 'samleapiurl.com',
       port: 80,
       path: '/getdata'
   };

   http.get(options, function(resp) {
       var body = '';

       resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
           body += chunk;
       });
       resp.on('end', function() {
           res.end(body);
       });
   }).on('error', function(e) {
       console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   });
   ```
2. https://samleapiurl.com:8443/getdata

   ```
   var options = {
       host: 'samleapiurl.com',
       port: 8443,
       path: '/getdata'
   };

   https.get(options, function(resp) {
       var body = '';

       resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
           body += chunk;
       });
       resp.on('end', function() {
           res.end(body);
       });
   }).on('error', function(e) {
       console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   });
   ```

2nd option doesn't work and it throws an error like

```
Got error: 10232:error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
internal error:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:741:
```

I'm not sure why i'm getting this error if try to access 8443 in https mode.
Is there anyone who faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might try restricting which ciphers tomcat can use, as noted in [this blog](http://blog.techstacks.com/2008/09/securing-ssl-in-tomcat-part-two.html), which suggests adding the following line to the SSL Connector section of server.xml:

```
ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```